# Floating divs on top of others divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create something like the following

```
 ------------------------------------------
|                 div 1                    |
|         __________________________       |
|        | div2 on top of div1/div3|       |
---------|-------------------------|-------
|        |        div2             |       |
|        |_________________________|       |
|  div3  |                         | div3  |
|        |        div4             |       |
|        |                         |       |
```

This is what I have so far..

```
<body>
   <div id='div1'></div>
   <div id='container'>
       <div id='div2'></div>
       <div id='div4'></div>
   </div>
   <div id='div3'></div>   
</body>

css
body{
   width:980px;
   margin:0 auto;
   position:relative;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;  
}

#container{
   position:absolute;
   top:15px;
}

#div1{
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

The problem is I want `div1` to extend the whole length instead of 980px here. I also want my div2 and div4 in the middle of the page. In my css the `div1` will only be like

```
 -------------------------
|         div 1           |
|_________________________|
| div2 on top of div1/div3|
|-------------------------|
|        div2             |
|_________________________|
|                         |
|        div4             |
|                         |
```

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: See the answer I gave to a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318869/create-a-floating-div-on-top-of-divs/20318894#20318894

Comment: @koenp That question was asked by him:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CuN7A/)

I added `background-color` and `height` just for the visibility. The idea was that you can create your `div1` and `div3` and you just absolutely position a 100% width container a bit lower than the relative `div1`. Than just add `div2` and `div4` with a smaller relative width like 80% to the container.

### HTML

```
<div id='div1'></div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='div2'></div>
    <div id='div4'></div>
</div>
<div id='div3'></div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#div3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
}
#div4 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

About your second question. Unfortunately you can't make `div3` to go as far as `div4` in pure CSS, because the container is taken out from the document flow when you give it an absolute position, so you can't create relative positioning according to it. However you can do the following hacks:

### [Manual calculation](http://jsfiddle.net/PT478/)

You have to calculate the heights by hand. `div4`'s height is `800px` and has a `100px` offset so `div3` has to be `900px` tall. Don't forget to add this too:

```
body{ margin: 0px; }
```

### [Background hack](http://jsfiddle.net/7w77v/)

If `div3` has a fix color, you can set your `body`'s color to the same with a zero margin:

```
body{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

### JavasScript

You can simply get and set the height of the `<div>`s via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have another question. How to extend my div3 height to as far as div4 goes. div4 could be dynamic height. I have updated your fd. http://jsfiddle.net/CuN7A/1/ +1 though

Comment: @FlyingCat I don't think you can do that with this DOM. But I edited my answer with a few workarounds you can try.